# Flatlist not scrolling inside absolute view?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-flatlist

Flat list is not scrolling inside absolute view here is my code but if i remove absolute it's working fine

```
<View style={{ flex: 1, marginTop: 8 }}>
        <Input ref={input => {
          this.input = input;
        }}
          onFocus={() => {
            this.setState({ showPicker: true })
          }}
          onEndEditing={() => {
            this.setState({ showPicker: false })
          }}>
        </Input>
        <View style={{ position: "relative", zIndex: 9999, margin: 8 }}>
          {
            this.state.showPicker ?
              <View style={{position:"absolute",width:"100%", backgroundColor: "white" }}>

                  <FlatList

                    data={["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"]}
                    showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
                    renderItem={({ item }) =>
                    <TouchableWithoutFeedback>
                      <View>
                        <View style={{ width: "100%", height: 50 }}>
                          <Text style={{ height: "100%", width: "100%" }}>{item}</Text>
                        </View>
                        <Divider />
                      </View>
                      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
                    }
                    keyExtractor={item => item}
                  />

                </View> : null
            }
          </View>        
      </View>
```

Comment: give that view a specific size

Comment: @CuongTranDuc not working.

Comment: did you set a height for the absolute view ?

Comment: yes height:100 not working

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem and solved by adding a View between absolute view and FlatList with height.
Setting `contentContainerStyle` to FlatList didn't work.

ex.

```
<View style={{position: 'absolute', top: 0, bottom: 0, etc..}}>
  <View style={{height: 300}}>
    <FlatList
      {...props}
    />
  </View>
</View>
```

Answer (score 4):

I faced this issue and all I did to solve it was changing the FlatList import from 'react-native' to 'react-native-gesture-handler':

`import { FlatList } from 'react-native-gesture-handler'`

Comment: I went back and forth, crossed over all internet, asked ChatGPT and couldn't make it work. 

It's an issue on the way Android handles absolute property. Since the container doesn't have enough room the scroll is not possible.

This is the correct answer. Add the library.

Answer (score 0):

Perfectly worked - Simply set `height` of parent element of `Flatlist` to `100%` like below and if needed then `contentContainerStyle={{ paddingBottom: 30 }}` to Flatlist -

```
<View style={{ height: '100%' }}>
    <FlatList
        data={["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"]}
        contentContainerStyle={{ paddingBottom: 30 }}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
    />
</View>
```

Happy Coding :)

Comment: Is there any reason, flexGrow does not work in `contentContainerStyle`

Answer (score 0):

I have used position:'absolute' then I import flatlist from react-native-gesture-handler.

Working fine.